# Why the service does not get an ClusterIP assigned?

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I am trying to deploy MinIO on K8s cluster and have followed the guide on https://github.com/minio/minio-operator/blob/master/README.md.

After the installation the MinIO services does not get a ClusterIP: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (a) don't post code snippets as images, it's [against the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); (b) the docs **very clearly** say they [create a headless service](https://github.com/minio/minio-operator/blob/master/docs/operator-fields.md#minio-operator-reference), and [describe how to create a real Service](https://github.com/minio/minio-operator/blob/master/docs/operator-fields.md#access-minioinstance-via-service)

Answer (score 6):

ClusterIp is "**None**" when you want to create a [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services). In your service template (yaml file) if clusterIp is set to "None" then cluster-ip is not assigned for your service.

If you need cluster-ip for your service then change your template and remove "**clusterIP: None**" field.